# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct

My problem is that I am facing error **"Unhandled exception at 0x00bd3364 in qualnet.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004."**.

The scenario is that I have defined a struct (NodesInfoTable) which is used in another struct (Node). Please note that I am using this code in a network simulator QualNet. I am getting error whenever I execute my code in the network simulator. However, if I execute my code in a separate project (test project) consisting of only this code, then this code executes correctly.

I think that there is some problem with memory allocation. But I wonder why it is running correctly in one project but not in another.

I also searched other post with similar title, but their problem is different. This is why, I used new post for my inquiry.

My code is provided below:

file: node.h

```
struct NodesInfoTable {
    int nodeId;
    int nodeStatus;
    list<int> channels;
};


struct Cluster {
    int clusterId;
    list<int> commonChannels;
    Cluster() {
        clusterId= -1;
    }
};



struct Node {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    Cluster* cluster;
    list<NodesInfoTable*> nodeTable;
};
```

file: node.cpp

```
Node* newNode;
newNode = (Node*) MEM_malloc(sizeof(Node));
.....
newNode->cluster = new Cluster();
newNode->nbTable = ??
....
```

file: myfile.cpp

```
NodesInfoTable nbTable1; 
nbTable1.nodeId = 1;
nbTable1.nodeStatus = 2;
node->nbTable.push_back(nbTable1); //'node' object is available here
```

I am getting error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00bd3364 in qualnet.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

on line:

> node->nbTable.push_back(nbTable1);

And the debugger navigate me to the code `_Nodeptr _Newnode = _Buynode(_Pnode, _Prevnode(_Pnode), _Val);` in file: list. Some more statements above and below this code are also mentioned below:

```
_Nodeptr _Pnode = _Where._Mynode();
_Nodeptr _Newnode = _Buynode(_Pnode, _Prevnode(_Pnode), _Val);
_Incsize(1);
_Prevnode(_Pnode) = _Newnode;
_Nextnode(_Prevnode(_Newnode)) = _Newnode;
```

Please not that I am correctly accessing 'cluster' object through 'node' object. However, the problem is with 'nbTable'. Since I have used statement `newNode->cluster = new Cluster()`, I think that this is why, memory is allocated to this object. But I dont have idea that how should I handle `newNode->nbTable = ??` because I think that it is the problem.

Thank you in advance and I look forward towards the solution.

Comment: And `node` is not zero?

Comment: Also, `nbTable` or `nodeTable`? And note that `nodeTable` is a vector of *pointers* while you push back a value that is *not* a pointer. Though, that would not even compile... So please post *actual* and *working* code. Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What on earth is `MEM_malloc` and why are you not using `new` here ??? How do you expect constructors to be called if you do this ?

Comment: Why do you allocate `Node` with `MEM_malloc` and `Cluster` with `new`? Why don't you use `new` for all heap allocations?

Comment: *anytime* you have an access violation hitting an address at some value (usually a power of 2) offset from 0x00000000, it almost assured you're dereferencing a NULL pointer (specifically,a member variable *through* a null pointer, in this case 4 bytes in on whatever the struct is). Now that said, stop `malloc`'ing in C++ code unless you *seriously* know what you're doing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thank you for your response. Yes, `node` is not zero and `nodeTable` is actually `nbTable`. Sorry, it is a mistake. Also the code is compiling correctly. 
Actually, I wish to know that how can I do `new` for the list of struct `newNode->nbTable`? (i.e. just like I did for `newNode->cluster`).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for your comment. I am confused that how can I use `new` for `list<NodesInfoTable*>`. If it would be simple `NodesInfoTable*` then I can easily use `new NodesInfoTable()` just like I did for `cluster`.

Comment: @MariusBancila Actually I am using network simulator, so `MEM_malloc` is by default used in the simulator. I have used `new` for the new structs which I am developing for my work.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your detailed explanation. I also do not want to use `malloc`. Instead I want to use `new` but I am confused that how can I use new for `list<NodesInfoTable*>`. If it would be simple `NodesInfoTable*` then I can easily use `new NodesInfoTable()` just like I did for `cluster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not validated it, but the comments basically spell it out.

You have the following structure:

```
struct Node {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    Cluster* cluster;
    list<NodesInfoTable*> nodeTable;
};
```

Which you allocated with:

```
Node* newNode;
newNode = (Node*) MEM_malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

I don't know exactly what `MEM_malloc` does, but the cast reviles that something, probably a `void*` is being cased to a `Node*`. If you look at the `Node` structure you have a `list<NodesInfoTable*>`, which is probably a `std::list`, which is a **class**.

As we all know, classes need their constructors to be run before they can be used properly. Allocating raw memory and casting it will not magically execute the constructor.

**If you see a class somewhere, use new!**

As a basic rule you should used `new` and `delete` with C++. *(If you know exactly what you are doing, exceptions may apply.)*

Comment: Previously, I was declaring as `list<NodesInfoTable*> nbTable ;` 
This is why, I was unable to do `new`, i.e., `newNode->nbTable = new list<NodesInfoTable>();`

However, its actual syntax is: `list<NodesInfoTable>* nbTable;` So, now I can easily do `newNode->nbTable = new list<NodesInfoTable>();` and the code is working fine.